# What is the difference between gravitational potential and gravitational potential energy and electrical potential and electrical potential energy?

Tags: forces, gravity, electricity, potential

I am in IB physics HL. I don't know much calculus but I would like to have an intuitive understanding of the difference between these two concepts.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between potential and potential energy is that the former is just the latter "per unit mass" or "per unit charge" for gravity and the electrostatic interaction respectively.

Answer (score 1):

"Potential" can be thought of as "specific potential energy" - it is an "intensive" version of potential energy, that is independent of the amount of "interactive stuff" that you have on hand.

(That said, in *quantum* mechanics, the *potential energy* function starts often getting called a "potential" for some reason that I don't know [and I find this usage a bit mhh].)